# Laptop 3 monitors - unable to save settings

Tags: windows-7, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have bought a usb display adapter to connect a 3rd monitor to the laptop (built in, HDMI, and external usb adapter).
The problem is that I can detect the 3rd monitor (connect via usb), but when saving its configuration (in the windows display settings) I am getting an error:

> unable to save settings...

Moreover, even if I disconnect the monitor, connect through the HDMI, the usb connected monitor is also not working.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You've been autocorrrected. I think your last senetence is "even if I disconnect the monitor connected through HDMI the USB connected monitor is not working also"

Comment: FWIW, I use two external monitors with my laptop. I have both of them connected to the USB docking station, but I think I have tried to coonect one to the HDMI port on the laptop, and one to te USB connector.

Comment: If your dongle use DisplayLink tech you could try the latest driver from their website. Also, you can try to disable UAC, if you haven't done that already.

Comment: what is UAC????

Comment: A security feature. Enter User Account Control in start menu search box, draw the slider all the way to the bottom. Then you have to reboot. But you should try to get drivers that will work with UAC.